# Computing integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(ax^2 + b)^k}$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I know this is a difficult integral to compute, and I know that the answer is:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(ax^2 + b)^k} = \frac{\sqrt\pi  \Gamma(k-\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(k)}\frac{1}{\sqrt a b^{k-\frac{1}{2}}}$.

However, I don't know how to work it out.

I would really appreciate any hints.

If anyone is able to work the answer, would it also be possible to compute it for different bounds for the integral? (e.g. once a suitable change in variable x is performed so that one integrates between $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$, could I integrate just between, let's say $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{-\pi}{4}$?).

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe residue theorem with poles at $\sqrt{-b/a}$? Are $a$ and $b$ real numbers?

Comment: Yes, b and a are real. a and k are strictly positive. I have never used the residue theorem before, could I get a hint on how to use it?

Comment: @D B Do you know how to calculate residue? Laurent series?

Comment: @Henry W. , regretfully, complex analysis is not my strong point. However, if you give me an idea of the steps needed to solve the integral I will surely try to work it out on my own.

Comment: @D B Use a semicircular contour on the upper half plane. By residue's theorem, the integral along that contour is $2\pi i$ times the total residue of enclosed poles. Then show that the integral on the semicircle vanishes as radius $\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\left(\frac ba\right)^{1/2}u$. Then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(ax^2+b)^k}=\frac1{\sqrt ab^{k-\frac12}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{(u^2+1)^k}=\frac2{\sqrt ab^{k-\frac12}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{du}{(u^2+1)^k}$$
Now let $t=\frac1{u^2+1}$. Then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(ax^2+b)^k}=\frac1{\sqrt ab^{k-\frac12}}\int_0^1t^{k-\frac32}(1-t)^{-\frac12}\,dt=\frac1{\sqrt ab^{k-\frac12}}\text{B}\left(k-\frac12,\frac12\right)$$
The key is to recognize the beta function in the answer and work towards that.

Comment: All too easy.  +1

Comment: You made it look easy :). Thank you!
But what if I wanted to work out the value of the integral between c1 and c2 instead of between $-\infty$ and $\infty$? Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, if you really needed the integral from $c_1$ to $c_2$, then that scale factor of $\left(\frac ba\right)^{\frac12}$ would be reflected in the limits in the first line above and if $c_1<0<c_2$, the folding operation would instead result in two integrals. Then we might end up with 2 [incomplete Beta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) at the end. If $2k$ were an integer, the substitution $t=\cos^2\theta$ would result in a feasible integral.